# Given a distance matrix is there an isometric embedding?

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, matrices

I have distance matrix $D$ that was calculated by some distance (non-Euclidean but satisfying distance requirements). Is there a set of points in some Euclidean space such that it generates matrix of Euclidean distances that is equal $D$?

I know that if $G=-HDH/2$ is p.d. where H is the centering matrix then such embedding exists. However, I don't have any information about $G$.

Comment: Choose one of the points are the origin.  Use the "polarization identity"
to write find $(x,y)$ for any other points $x,y$ using the known distances
$|x|^2$, $|y|^2$, $|x+y|^2$.  The embedding problem can be solved **iff**
the resulting Gram matrix is positive-definite.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry_problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The magic words are [Cayley-Menger](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html), but an explicit answer is given [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12394/representability-of-finite-metric-spaces)