# Is every finite metric space representable in a pseudo-Euclidean space?

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lorentzian-geometry

Let $X$ be a finite set with a (true) metric $d$ and $|X| = n$. Does there exist a set $Y$ of $n$ points in $R^n$ with a pseudo-Riemannian metric with signature $(n - k, k, 0)$ for some integer $k$ such that the matrix of distances between points is the same?

Background: I've been trying to understand Multidimensional Scaling (MDS) and what happens when there are negative eigenvalues in the inner-product matrix. I know from [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12394/representability-of-finite-metric-spaces) that a true metric does not guarantee a positive-definite inner-product matrix. In other words, there are finite metric spaces that are not representable in Euclidean space.

However, every example I've seen can produce a non-distorted embedding so long as some of the dimensions are allowed to have imaginary values. In these examples, the imaginary dimensions correspond to negative eigenvalues of the inner-product matrix when performing MDS. Is this always the case? If we allow some dimensions of the embedding to be imaginary, will MDS always produce an exact embedding?

I'm also a bit unsure on the terminology, so I apologize if this question has already been asked with more precise language.

Comment: If asked whether every finite metric space is isometric to a subset of Euclidean space with the usual metric, the first thing I think of is the set $\{1,\ldots,n\} \cup\{p\}$ where the distance between two points in $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is just the absolute difference, and the distance from $p$ to any other point is $1.$ But if $p$ is the north pole and $1,\ldots, n$ are on the equator and distance is measured along the surface of the earth, then that's it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Does that satisfy the triangle inequality when $n>3$?

Comment: REVISION OF A HASTY COMMENT: If asked whether every finite metric space is isometric to a subset of Euclidean space with the usual metric, the first thing I think of is the set $\{1,\ldots,n\} \cup \{p\}$ where the distance between two points in $\{ 1, \ldots, n\}$ is just the absolute difference, and the distance from $p$ to any other point is bigger than any distance between two of those $n$ points. But if $p$ is the north pole and $1,\ldots,n$ are on the equator and distance is measured along the surface of the earth, then that's it. @JamesHanson