# Gram matrix determinant in dimension 4 and $E_8$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

Consider a determinant of a Gram matrix in dimension $4$.

$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -\cos(\alpha_1) & -\cos(\alpha_2) & -\cos(\alpha_3)\\
-\cos(\alpha_1) & 1 & -\cos(\alpha_6)& -\cos(\alpha_5)\\
 -\cos(\alpha_2) & -\cos(\alpha_6) & 1& -\cos(\alpha_4)\\
 -\cos(\alpha_3) & -\cos(\alpha_5) & -\cos(\alpha_4)& 1\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

and expand it by opening all brackets and using the identity

$$\cos(\alpha_i)=\dfrac{e^{\alpha_i}+e^{-\alpha_i}}{2}.$$

One gets the following answer:
\begin{equation}
G_T=-\frac{1}{8}\sum_{r\cdot e_7=0} (-1)^{r\cdot e_8}\chi(r)+\frac{1}{16}\sum_{\substack{r \cdot e_8 \neq 0\\
                  r\cdot e_7\neq 0}}\chi(2r)-1.
\end{equation}
Here $r$ goes along all roots of $E_8,$ $e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_8$ are some pairwise orthogonal roots of $E_8$ and $\chi$ is a character, defined by the rule $\chi(2e_i)=e^{2i\alpha_i}$ for $i\leq 6$, $\chi(2e_7)=\chi(2e_8)=1.$
From this expression one immediately sees that the Gram matrix determinant does not change under Regge symmetries (see this question [Unusual symmetries of the Cayley-Menger determinant for the volume of tetrahedra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259664/unusual-symmetries-of-the-cayley-menger-determinant-for-the-volume-of-tetrahedra)).

**Question** Is there a Lie algebra explanation of that? Do there exist any similar identities for other root systems?

Comment: What are $e_L$ and $e_A$?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, this is a typo.