# More mysterious properties of Gram matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hyperbolic-geometry, matrix-analysis, determinants

This is another question related to the mysterious properties of the Gram matrix in dimension $4$. Here's the [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/325830/91764).

The following fact could be extracted from [0402087](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0402087):

> For any $a_i\neq 0$ a polynomial
>
> $$(t+a_1a_2a_3)(t+a_2a_4a_6)(t+a_1a_5a_6)(t+a_3a_4a_5)-$$
>
> $$(t-a_1a_2a_4a_5)(t-a_1a_3a_4a_6)(t-a_2a_3a_5a_6)(t-1)$$
>
> has a nonzero double root if and only if Gram determinant
>
> $$
> \begin{vmatrix}
> 1 & -\frac{a_1+\frac{1}{a_1}}{2}& -\frac{a_2+\frac{1}{a_2}}{2}&-\frac{a_3+\frac{1}{a_3}}{2} \\
>  -\frac{a_1+\frac{1}{a_1}}{2} & 1 &-\frac{a_6+\frac{1}{a_6}}{2}&-\frac{a_5+\frac{1}{a_5}}{2}\\
>  -\frac{a_2+\frac{1}{a_2}}{2} & -\frac{a_6+\frac{1}{a_6}}{2} & 1&-\frac{a_4+\frac{1}{a_4}}{2}\\
> -\frac{a_3+\frac{1}{a_3}}{2}  & -\frac{a_5+\frac{1}{a_5}}{2}  & -\frac{a_4+\frac{1}{a_4}}{2} & 1\\
> \end{vmatrix}
> $$
>
> vanishes.

**Question:** How to prove it? I was able only to verify it in Maple.